# execute order of functions in javascript (event driven language )

Tags: javascript, function, execute

I am confused about the example in http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/

```
function do_a(){
// simulate a time consuming function
    setTimeout( function(){
    console.log( '`do_a`: this takes longer than `do_b`' );
}, 1000 );
}

function do_b(){
    console.log( '`do_b`: this is supposed to come out after `do_a` but it comes out before      `do_a`' );
}

do_a();
do_b();
```

results

```
`do_b`: this is supposed to come out after `do_a` but it comes out before `do_a`
`do_a`: this takes longer than `do_b`
```

and the author's explanation is "However javascript is an event driven language. If do_a takes longer than do_b, the result of do_b comes out first than do_a;". I am still not quite clear, please explain in details, or please point me to some specific material, thank you,

Comment: This might help http://www.slideshare.net/fgalassi/event-driven-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout says to execute its function after 1 second. Each function returns immediately, while setTimeout executes after that time.

In actuality, do_a() and do_b() are executing in order. But the results of setTimeout are independent of do_a or do_b.

Further, that is a poor example of callback function execution since setTimeout has nothing to do with a callback. A better example is as follows:

```
var a = function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback();
    }, 1000);

    console.log('1');
}

var b = function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback();
    }, 2000);
    console.log('2');
}

a(function(){
    console.log('3');
});
b(function(){
    console.log('4');
});
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is a better callback example, does it related to some concepts in "event driven language"?

Comment: Imagine that you're a spider, but with any number of legs. Each leg rests on its on thread of web. If any bug lands anywhere on the web, you just have to reach out a leg to deal with it. Each leg is listening for the vibrations of an insect hitting that thread. The leg resting on that thread can grab the bug on its own while the other legs patiently sit waiting on their threads. If two or more thread vibrate at the same time, each leg can each grab its own insect without requiring the entire spider to move. Events are like this. You can listen lots of events and assign a function for each one.

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple to understand, I watched Spider-Man too, :), I may need grab a book to get deeper about event driven, thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I highly recommend Javascript the Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. Its an excellent guide to the language.

Answer (score 0):

do_a() and do_b() are executed immediately one after the other. When do_a() executes, it starts a timer which prints the output in 1000ms (after the output of do_b() has been printed)

So they do execute in order, it just doesnt wait for a response

Comment: ie: one is not dependent on the other to complete before it continues executing

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you are running an anonymous function in your setTimeout. This is completely independent of the two original functions you created

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am a rookie, does it related to some concepts in "event driven language"? Because I think it is different from "the traditional programming model which is a batch programming model", thank you